# Inequalities of standard centered Gaussian random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions

**Problem:** Let $g$ be a standard centered Gaussian random variable, show that for all $t > 0$
\begin{align*}
     \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left(\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{t^3}\right) e^{-t^2 / 2} \leq \mathbb{P}(g \geq t) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \frac{1}{t} e^{-t^2 / 2} \tag{1.3}
\end{align*}

**My attempt:** First, for any $t >0$, we show that
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(g \ge t) \le \dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-t^2/2}.
\end{align*}
Since $g$ is a standard Gaussian random variable, then
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(g \ge t) & = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^{+\infty} e^{-u^2/2}du\\
    & \le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{t}^{+\infty} \dfrac{u}{t} e^{-u^2/2}du \\
    & = \dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{t}^{+\infty} ue^{-u^2/2} = \dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[-e^{-u^2/2}\right]_{t}^{+\infty} = \dfrac{1}{t\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-t^2/2}
\end{align*}

For the remaining part, I tried with $1 \ge t/u$ but failed with this approach. I hope anyone could give me some hints if possible.

Comment: Try by parts; $\int_t^\infty e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du = - \frac{1}{u}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}} |_{t}^\infty - \int_t^\infty \frac{1}{u^2} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du $ and repeat your argument for integral (now the signs are different) getting the bound by $\int_t^\infty \frac{u}{t^3} e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du$. It should give you what is needed.

Comment: @Presage Thank you for your hint. It was very helpful. I have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\because \left[ \left( \frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \right] ^{\prime}=\frac{x^4-3}{x^4}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}<1
&\\
&\therefore \displaystyle\int_{\boldsymbol{t}}^{\infty}{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}
&\\
&\ge \displaystyle\int_{\boldsymbol{t}}^{\infty}{\frac{x^4-3}{x^4}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx}
&\\
&=\left( \frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x} \right) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\mid_{\boldsymbol{t}}^{\infty}
&\\
&=\left( \frac{1}{\boldsymbol{t}}-\frac{1}{\boldsymbol{t}^3} \right) e^{-\frac{\boldsymbol{t}^2}{2}}
&
\end{align}